# YOLOv5 vs YOLOv8 tensorboard - viewing internal neural network architecture

Tags: tensorboard, yolo, yolov5, yolov8

When I train a YOLOv5 model and open tensorboard, I have 4 tabs: *Time series*, *Scalars*, *Images*, *Graphs*. Graphs is particularly useful because it allows me to view internal network structure and guides me when trying to extract the output of some intermediate layer.

[YOLOv5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFvdO.png)

However, I recently started using YOLOv8 and I cannot find that option. I only have Time series and Scalars tabs. In what way can I see architecture graph (*Graphs* tab)?

[YOLOv8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93iPN.png)